# Angular Material Table - Only include "selected" rows in Submit()

Tags: angular-material, mat-table

I am using a matTable with a matTableDataSource to generate a data table that allows each row to be selected or deselected by checkbox in the first column of each row.

When a form containing the table is submitted, currently all rows are being submitted regardless if selected or not.

Is it possible to limit the data submitted to only those rows that are selected? Here is an example of the current data on submit:

```
myTableData: [
  {
    "selected": true,
    "dataCell1": "9279694138",
    "dataCell2": "Some value",
    "dataCell3": "00010-00/8.1"
  },
  {
    "selected": false,
    "dataCell1": "5730371160",
    "dataCell2": "Some value",
    "dataCell3": "00010-00/8.2",
  },
  {
    "selected": true,
    "dataCell1": "1234567890",
    "dataCell2": "Some value",
    "dataCell3": "00010-00/8.4"
  },
  etc...
]
```

In the example above, since the second record was not selected by the end user ("selected": false), I would like it to be removed from the table's submitted data object.

Does the mat-table have a method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything built in to the mat-table to achieve this. You would need to filter the data manually before submission. They do document a case for adding selection to a mat-table: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#selection

Even with this, you would need to add manual filtering before submitting.

This is easily achieved by something like this:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  myTableData: any[] = [...];

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  submit() {
    const data = this.myTableData.filter((item) => item.selected);
    if (data && data.length) {
      this.http.post("/my/api/endpoint", data).subscribe()
    }
  }
}
```